# Bump websocket-extensions from 0.1.3 to 0.1.4

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github, npm, websocket

I moved my project to github with that got multiple security alerts from dependabot.
All errors are related to some external dependencies, to fix those i updated versions in package.json and issue got fixed.

But
websocket-extensions has no dependencies in package.json.
Now question is how we can update this package which doesnot have dependency in package.json.
I tried "**npm audit fix**" than also it is not fixed.

On "**npm audit fix**" getting - fixed 0 of 0 vulnerabilities in 2142 scanned packages

With some research found that this(websocket-extensions) dependency might be coming from "firebase" upgraded firebase to "^7.23.0" still getting same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm audit fix` should actually do it.  You have to commit the changes to package-lock.json before GitHub will recognize it as fixed.  package-lock.json contains all the versions for all the transitive dependencies, even those that are not explicitly mentioned in package.json.

Comment: getting Fixed 0 of 0 vulnerabilities in 2142 scanned packages on npm audit fix, package.json and package-lock.json, already commited after previous fix from "npm audit fix"

Comment: What version of npm are you using?

Comment: npm version - 6.13.4

Comment: [Here's an example of what should happen](https://github.com/CodingDoug/universal-translator/pull/1/files).  I did this for several repositories of mine.  You could make the change manually if you want, or simply delete package-lock.json and all of node_modules, then start over with `npm install`.

Comment: Thanks @Doug stevenson. Deleting node modules and package-lock.json worked